# X-and-Y-lined streets or X and Y-lined streets?

Tags: grammar

My intuition told me it should be written, for example, as:

> restaurant and bar-lined streets.

However, after a [Google Book search](https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=ubuntu&hs=uK7&biw=1855&bih=984&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNTlDBc9twHEvrO7I2buZ5wrUDbIXQ%3A1568373059641&ei=Q3l7XdveJrTdmAXS5KWICA&q=%22and%20restaurant-lined%20streets%22&oq=%22and%20restaurant-lined%20streets%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...47164.48478.0.48576.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.NyMHAPdXUVk), I found this format:

> shop- and restaurant-lined streets

What the correct or at least common way of formatting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is common to append a 'suspension (or suspended) hyphen' to the items preceding the last in a list of hyphenated terms forming consecutive compounds.

> I cannot eat egg-, gluten-, or salt-containing foods.

A space follows a suspension hyphen unless a comma is needed. However, there is no single "rule"; it is a matter of style. If you don’t like using sus­pended hyphens, you could re-cast their sen­tences to avoid them. If you must use them, and if producing material for publication, or academic submission, or simply to be consistent, you should consult the appropriate style guide. For example, the Chicago Manual of Style (5.91.4) says:

> If two phrasal adjectives **end** in a common element, the ending element
>   should appear only with the second phrase, and a suspension hyphen
>   should follow the unattached words to show that they are related to
>   the ending element: middle- and upper-class operagoers. But if two
>   phrasal adjectives **begin** with a common element, a hyphen is usually
>   inappropriate, and the element should be repeated: left-handed and
>   left-brained executives.

(my emphasis) (a link would only take you to a paywall) however...

[Grammar Tip - suspended hyphen](https://ontariotraining.net/suspended-hyphen/)

[Suspended hyphens](https://erinwrightwriting.com/suspended-hyphens/)

Answer (score 2):

The second form is what I would generally use; this is known as a [suspended hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Suspended_hyphens). There is a question on the English Language stack exchange about them here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113422/how-to-use-hyphens-appropriately-when-listing-multiple-hyphenated-terms
The answer given there shows that this is acceptable and sometimes essential usage.

Comment: As a reminder, answers which consist only of links are frowned upon. You should summarize or excerpt the information found at the link, particularly as links can go bad — even those to another Stack, as questions are sometimes deleted years after they are posed, when deemed no longer to fit the quality or scope of the site.